# onComplete SetAnimation problem

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

void    SetAnimation (const common::PoseAnimationPtr &_anim, boost::function< void()> _onComplete)

With the second parameter...I'm trying to do "Things to try on your own" section in the wiki of Gazebo, "Controlling a Robot"...

Here is my code:

```
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include "common/CommonTypes.hh"
#include "common/Animation.hh"
#include "common/KeyFrame.hh"
#include "physics/Entity.hh"
#include "physics/World.hh"
#include "gazebo.hh"

namespace gazebo
{
  class AnimationTest : public WorldPlugin
  {
    public: void Load(physics::WorldPtr _parent, sdf::ElementPtr /*_sdf*/)
    {
      gazebo::common::PoseAnimationPtr anim(
          new gazebo::common::PoseAnimation("test", 1000.0, true));

      gazebo::common::PoseAnimationPtr anim2(
          new gazebo::common::PoseAnimation("test2", 1000.0, true));

      gazebo::common::PoseKeyFrame *key;

      gazebo::common::PoseKeyFrame *key2;

      key = anim->CreateKeyFrame(0);
      key->SetTranslation( math::Vector3(0,0,0) );
      key->SetRotation( math::Quaternion(0,0,0) );

      key = anim->CreateKeyFrame(10.0);
      key->SetTranslation( math::Vector3(5,0,0) );
      key->SetRotation( math::Quaternion(0,0,1.5707) );

      key2 = anim2->CreateKeyFrame(0);
      key2->SetTranslation( math::Vector3(0,0,0) );
      key2->SetRotation( math::Quaternion(0,0,0) );

      key2 = anim2->CreateKeyFrame(10.0);
      key2->SetTranslation( math::Vector3(0,3,0) );
      key2->SetRotation( math::Quaternion(0,0,0) );

      _parent->GetEntity("box_model")->SetAnimation(anim);
      _parent->GetEntity("box_model2")->SetAnimation(anim2, anim);
    }
  };
  // Register this plugin with the simulator
  GZ_REGISTER_WORLD_PLUGIN(AnimationTest)
}
```

Thank you so much!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1133/oncomplete-setanimation-problem.../) by [pablogaralv](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/181/pablogaralv/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 15 on 2013-01-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The second parameter to SetAnimation is a boost function pointer. The function pointer will be called when the animation is complete. This lets you set and animation, and get a callback on completion.

Here is the api:
http://gazebosim.org/api/1.3.1/classgazebo_1_1physics_1_1Entity.html#a0ba2d580de851fabb0ef90f8e53bedcd

What you can do is:

```
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include "common/CommonTypes.hh"
#include "common/Animation.hh"
#include "common/KeyFrame.hh"
#include "physics/Entity.hh"
#include "physics/World.hh"
#include "gazebo.hh"

namespace gazebo
{
  class AnimationTest : public WorldPlugin
  {
    public: void Callback()
    {
      printf("Animation complete\n");
    }

    public: void Load(physics::WorldPtr _parent, sdf::ElementPtr /*_sdf*/)
    {
      gazebo::common::PoseAnimationPtr anim(
          new gazebo::common::PoseAnimation("test", 1000.0, true));

      gazebo::common::PoseAnimationPtr anim2(
          new gazebo::common::PoseAnimation("test2", 1000.0, true));

      gazebo::common::PoseKeyFrame *key;

      gazebo::common::PoseKeyFrame *key2;

      key = anim->CreateKeyFrame(0);
      key->SetTranslation( math::Vector3(0,0,0) );
      key->SetRotation( math::Quaternion(0,0,0) );

      key = anim->CreateKeyFrame(10.0);
      key->SetTranslation( math::Vector3(5,0,0) );
      key->SetRotation( math::Quaternion(0,0,1.5707) );

      key2 = anim2->CreateKeyFrame(0);
      key2->SetTranslation( math::Vector3(0,0,0) );
      key2->SetRotation( math::Quaternion(0,0,0) );

      key2 = anim2->CreateKeyFrame(10.0);
      key2->SetTranslation( math::Vector3(0,3,0) );
      key2->SetRotation( math::Quaternion(0,0,0) );

      _parent->GetEntity("box_model")->SetAnimation(anim);
      _parent->GetEntity("box_model2")->SetAnimation(anim2,
        boost::bind(&AnimationTest::Callback, this));
    }
  };
  // Register this plugin with the simulator
  GZ_REGISTER_WORLD_PLUGIN(AnimationTest)
}
```

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-01-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1